# Получение элемента массива

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не могу получить элемент со значением `6` в массиве:

```
mylist = [1, 2, [18, 45, 87, [7, 6]]]
```

На `myList[2][1]` выдаёт `45`. На `myList[3][1]` выдаёт ошибку:

> IndexError: list index out of range

Как добраться до третьего массива?

Comment: А для чего двумя способами? Это учебное задание? Тогда делайте сами.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это задание, а не вопрос.

Comment: Конечно вас "неправильно поняли" - ведь изначальная версия вопроса радикально отличалась от текущей.

Comment: `myList[2][3][1]` пробовали использовать?

Comment: Розмещайте как правильный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как `6` - второй элемент в массиве `[7, 6]`, который является 4м элементом в массиве `[18, 45, 87, [7, 6]]`, который в свою очередь является 3м элементом в массиве `mylist`, то для доступа к нему нужно писать так:

```
myList[2][3][1]
```